# Xamarin.Forms UWP app Xamarin Editor View Wont Show Content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am seeing a wired problem on Xamarin.Forms UWP app.  This is Xamarin crossplatform app using .NETStandard 2, so code is not platform specific but part of .NETStandard library (or what was called before PCL).

I am establishing TCPIP connection to a server and getting some data from server successfully in all 3 platforms Android, iOS, and UWP.

That is all good and working.

The problem I am seeing is bit stupid.  I am u Xamarin Editor control to show output from server.  The Editor control is supposed to expand to show all new text added to it.  And it does so on Android or iOS but not on UWP.  Even more, on UWP, no text is displayed from the received message but the message is received successfuly and I can see it in debug mode by howering over the msg variable below or over editorResponse.Text property

```
private void ReadResponse()
{
    if (serverStream.CanRead)
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder receivedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        int readSoFar = 0;

        do
        {
            //serverSteam is an instance of System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
            readSoFar = serverStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            receivedMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, readSoFar));
        } 
        while (serverStream.DataAvailable);

        string msg = receivedMessage.ToString().Trim();

        //PROBLEM IS HERE AND ON UWP ONLY!  BOTH IOS AND ANDROID ARE FINE
        //hower over msg or editorResponse.Text
        //and I see both have correct received 
        //information from server but editorResponse Editor 
        //control wont show it
        //Hardcoding dummy string will show correct however
        editorResponse.Text = msg; // this is Xamarin Editor view

        //If I put message into a Label control, it shows just fine
        lblResponse.Text = msg;  // this works!
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Cannot read from NetworkStream", "Close");
    }
}
```

this is how my Editor is set in XAML

```
    <Editor x:Name="editorResponse" 
        Text="Server response will show here"
        AutoSize="TextChanges"
        IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        VerticalOptions="Fill">
    </Editor>
```

Comment: Have you tried updating `editorResponse.Text` on the UI thread :  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {  editorResponse.Text = msg; });`

Comment: This is not Async processing, all is happening on UI thread.  But yes, I just tried that and same issue, nothing shows in Editor

Comment: Not sure what you "mean" by async processing, but networking on the main thread is a no-no, so that code should be running on a background thread and your UI updating on the UI/Main thread.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember.  You are right it is no-no but interestingly, I use TcpClient and NetworkStream and no issues whatsoever in Android, iOS and UWP.  The only issue I see is that it wont update Editor.text for some reason as described above.  This is just a small app sending short message and receiving short message, just a proof of concept basically.

Comment: A bug in the UWP's implementation of Editor: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4611

Comment: Perhaps, not sure though since if I just hardcode string in the msg, it works

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even if I force the UI update to be on a non-UI thread. The app crashes if update it done on a non-UI thread. The github issue seems more about getting the size of the Editor in code after it resizes with a text change. Is there perhaps some character in the response that may be causing some bug? If you hardcode the exact same string that you get from the socket response, does the issue occur? And is the issue that the Editor is not resized when the text is changed or that the text is not changed? Did you try `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {...});`

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT Thanks.  I tried using BeginInvokeOnMainThread, it makes no difference.  The Editor is neither resizing, nor it is displaying the text I receive in response.  However, howering over response varialbe shows the text is received as it should.  I replaced Editor with Label and text is then displayed fine.  The Editor wont work only on UWP. On Android and IOS, both Editor and Label will show response message correctly.  On UWP, only Label will show it.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you on? What version of the Windows 10 SDKs do you have installed? I would make sure you are on the latest of everything. To check the Windows 10 version number, open Settings > System > About and look in the Windows Specifications section for "version" and "OS build."

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1803, OS build: 17134.523